# Java : Simple access for nested List<Object> on Entity

Tags: java, list, entity

I have an Entity with multiple nested lists like this :

```
public class DataFile  {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private List<DataObject> datas = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class DataObject {
    @Id
    private String type;
    private List<DataValue> values = new ArrayList<>();
}


public class DataValue  {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String dataValue;
    private LocalDateTime dataDate = LocalDateTime.now();
}
```

If I want a specific dataValue with DataObject.type = "speType" and DataValue.id = 2, I need this:

```
String value = dataFile.getDatas().forEach(t -> {
                 if(t.getType().equals("speType")){
                    t.getValues().forEach(v -> {
                        if(v.getId(2))
                            return v.getDataValue();
                    });
                  }
               });
```

Is it possible to create a simple method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that :

```
Optional<String> optValue =
        dataFile.getDatas()
                .stream()
                .filter(t -> t.getType().equals("specType"))
                .flatMap(t -> t.getValues().stream()
                           .filter(v -> v.getId() == 2)
                           .map(DataValue::getDataValue)
                )
                .findFirst();
```

`Stream.findFirst()` allows to exit of the processing early as soon as one element of it matches to the conditions. Similarly to what you did in your actual code.

Note that `Stream.findFirst()` returns an `Optional`. 
Either unwrap the object after the terminal operation such as :

```
String value = optValue.orElse("default value");
```

Or do in this stream itself :

```
String value = 
     ...
     .findFirst();
     .orElse("defaultValue")
```

Answer (score 0):

For a pure "stream" solution :

```
dataFile.getDatas()
            .stream()
            .filter(t -> t.getType().equals("speType"))
            .flatMap(t -> t.getValues().stream())
            .filter(v -> v.getId()==2)
            .map(DataValue::getDataValue)
            .findFirst();
```

I assumed that by "if(v.getId(2))" you meant "if(v.getId()==2)", if not you can easily change the code above.